# How getting data from MySQL with Recycle view

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to use Recycle View instead List View to get data from mysql, i already saw how create a recycle view from array of strings like:

```
`String[] models = new String[]{"Gallardo", "Vyron", "Corvette", "Pagani Zonda", "Porsche 911 Carrera", "BMW 720i", "DB77", "Mustang", "Camaro", "CT6"};`
```

But I don't know how load from php like:

```
`{"db_evento":[{"id":"3","nome":"Almo\u00e7o na casa de isa","local":"Navegantes, valthier apto 301","valor":"0.00","categoria":"Familiar ","descricao":"Toda a fam\u00edlia"},{"id":"6","nome":"Above","local":"Chevrolet ","valor":"150.00","categoria":"Shows","descricao":"Above and beyond no Chevrolet hall, as 22h dia 05\/06\/2014"},{"id":"7","nome":"Passeio de catamaram ","local":"Porto","valor":"15.00","categoria":"Passeio ","descricao":"Passeio de catamaram por recife "},{"id":"8","nome":"Corrida","local":"Ca\u00e7ad\u00e3o boa viagem ","valor":"0.00","categoria":"Passeio ","descricao":"Corrida de Cooper no calcadao de boa viagem as 7h"}],"success":1}`
```

or from json like:

```
``{"orders":[
            {"id":"681","item":"Pizza"},
            {"id":"690","item":"Pasta"},
            {"id":"701","item":"Coke"},
            {"id":"710","item":"Burger"},
            {"id":"720","item":"Finger-Chips"},
            {"id":"730","item":"Noodles"}
            ],``
```

Comment: First download json from your webserver using some Http client and then parse JSON in your app.

Comment: Please visit [Androidhive - Android HttpRequest, JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: i know how to parse json but i don't know how recycle view can get it, please help me

Answer (score 0):

The title of your questions seams different from the development of your problem. 
If you need to populate a recycle view with the data from a MySql you'll gonna need to add some extra code to your adapter. It's pretty simple actually. I'm typing some snippet to get you going. Hope it helps.

```
class MyAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;    
private Cursor cursor; // Your data
public MyAdapter( Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  this.context = context;
  this.cursor = cursor;
}

 public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    if (this.cursor == cursor) {
        return null;
    }
    Cursor oldCursor = this.cursor;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    if (cursor != null) {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return oldCursor;
}
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
    if (old != null) {
        old.close();
    }
}
```